# iPhone: Create a screenshot programmatically and then add it as a subview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, methods

I would like to call a method which takes a screenshot and then load this screenshot as a subview. I am using Apples sample code on how to take a screen shot (see below) and was trying to use the result (an image) in my code. However, I don't really know how to get the image from the method into my code. This is what I tried; it's obviously wrong, but it's all I could come up with:

```
    // Test Screenshot:

screenShot = [UIImage screenshot]; // THIS DOESN'T WORK
screenShotView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:screenShot];
[screenShotView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[self.view addSubview:screenShotView];
```

And this is Apple's sample code for the method:

```
 - (UIImage*)screenshot 
{
    NSLog(@"Shot");

    // Create a graphics context with the target size
    // On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into consideration
    // On iOS prior to 4, fall back to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
    CGSize imageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Iterate over every window from back to front
    for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) 
    {
        if (![window respondsToSelector:@selector(screen)] || [window screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])
        {
            // -renderInContext: renders in the coordinate space of the layer,
            // so we must first apply the layer's geometry to the graphics context
            CGContextSaveGState(context);
            // Center the context around the window's anchor point
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [window center].x, [window center].y);
            // Apply the window's transform about the anchor point
            CGContextConcatCTM(context, [window transform]);
            // Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
                                  -[window bounds].size.width * [[window layer] anchorPoint].x,
                                  -[window bounds].size.height * [[window layer] anchorPoint].y);

            // Render the layer hierarchy to the current context
            [[window layer] renderInContext:context];

            // Restore the context
            CGContextRestoreGState(context);
        }
    }

    // Retrieve the screenshot image
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thanks.

---

EDIT: This is the viewDidLoad method in which I create a TextView and then try to capture a screen shot of it:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {


    // Setup TextView:

    NSString* someText = @"Some Text";
    CGRect frameText = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480); 
    aTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:frameText];
    aTextView.text = someText;  
[self.view addSubview:aTextView];


    // Test Screenshot:

    screenShotView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self screenshot]];
    [screenShotView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];
    [self.view addSubview:screenShotView];

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:screenShotView];

    [super viewDidLoad];



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the image just change this line

```
screenShot = [UIImage screenshot];
```

To

```
screenShot = [self screenshot];
```

Edit: Check to see if the [self screenshot] returns a valid image or nil.

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {


    // Setup TextView:

    NSString* someText = @"Some Text";
    CGRect frameText = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480); 
    aTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:frameText];
    aTextView.text = someText;  
    [self.view addSubview:aTextView];


    // Test Screenshot:

    UIImage *screenShotImage = [self screenShot];
    if(screenShot){
            screenShotView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:screenShotImage];
            [screenShotView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];
            [self.view addSubview:screenShotView];

            [self.view bringSubviewToFront:screenShotView];
    }else
         NSLog(@"Something went wrong in screenShot method, the image is nil");

    [super viewDidLoad];



}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but somehow this doesn't seem to work. The method is now called, but I do not seem to get any image from the method. My subview is empty. Is there something else I've overlooked? thanks

Comment: Well it depends on how you invoce a method where you have this code: `screenShot = [UIImage screenshot]; // THIS DOESN'T WORK
screenShotView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:screenShot];
[screenShotView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[self.view addSubview:screenShotView];` Please always paste the entire method as it is hard to know what exactly you are doing.

Comment: @Cyprian: I updated the code above and included my entire viewDidLoad method where I try to capture the screen. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @n.evermind Don't know what is wrong so far, but look at my Edit, I added a code that validates the image and checks if it's nil. It would mean that something is wrong in the method for taking a screenshot.

Comment: @Cyprian: The method screenshot (not capital S - I'm sorry about this confusion) does return a valid image apparently. I don't get the NSLog message. So I guess there is something wrong with me trying to display the screenshot. Will try to save it to the photoLibrary, perhaps that will show whether or not a screenshot was actually taken. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Just a hunch: Could the problem be that you're setting the text, capturing the image, and displaying it all within viewDidLoad? Maybe the view isn't updating its display before you capture the screenshot. You could test this by making a separate IBAction for each step and calling them through button actions. And/or call setNeedsDisplay on the view, both before capturing the screenshot and after applying it.

Comment: @Wienke: Thanks, that works, you were exactly right. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @n.evermind: You're welcome. And I appreciate having the screenshot example. I'm using something similar in Cocoa but haven't tried it on the iPhone.